# Can't invoke namespace with 'use' keyword

Tags: unit-testing, namespaces, phpunit

I am learning about PHPUnit but at the very beginning, something trivial made me stumble.

that's Receipt PHP file inside src folder -

```
namespace TDD;

class Receipt {
    public function total(array $items = []) {
        return array_sum($items);
    }
}
```

And that's the ReceiptTest.php file inside tests folder -

```
namespace TDD\Test;
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use TDD\Receipt;

class ReceiptTest extends TestCase {
    public function testTotal() {
        $Receipt = new Receipt();
        $this->assertEquals(
            14,
            $Receipt->total([0,2,5,8]),
            'When summming the total should equal 15'
        );
    }
}
```

And that's the error log when I run vendor\bin\phpunit -

```
PHPUnit 7.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 98 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) TDD\Test\ReceiptTest::testTotal
Error: Class 'TDD\Receipt' not found

C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnit\tests\ReceiptTest.php:10

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all Your composer.json file in main project folder should be like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/"
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9"
    }
}
```

Then run in terminal *composer dump-autoload* to create new autoload file.
Afther this try run test  *vendor/bin/phpunit tests*

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you use Composer. If so then just include `phpunit` into your `composer.json` development requirements like this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
...
```

After the install you get a `bin` folder inside the `vendor` folder with `phpunit` autoloaded and ready to go. You can run it with `$ php src/vendor/bin/phpunit`.